# jQuery ScrollTop: Each animation needs to be finished before jumping to the next one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I'm using a live search plugin that uses `scrollTop` to scroll to found text on the page.
The code use keyboard arrow keys `up` and `down` to choose between results, the only problem is that due to the animation time of the `scrollTop`, the last action result won't be achieved before the result from the previous actions haven't been achieved after the animation time that is specified in the code.

What it means is that if I press `down` key too many times in a row, let's say 10 times, after the last item have been found on page, even if I immediately press the `up` key, I'll have to wait until the last 10 events have been executed, then it will execute the last event that uses the `up` key.

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: mark.offset().top-100}, 100);
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/70okvfr1/6/)

Is there anyway to cancel the previous event and jump to the next one if the key is pressed at the same time the animation is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I see the lag now, you will need to create a queue with jQuery first then clear it when the search changes direction with:

```
$(element).clearQueue();
```

I couldn't recreate the laggy effect you described. But there is a function in jquery animate you can use to achieve this.

```
$(element).stop()
```

I updated your jsFiddle to stop the previous animation before starting a new one, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/70okvfr1/7/).

Also you can read more about `.stop()` [here](https://api.jquery.com/stop/).

Comment: Even in your fiddle, the same problem persists. Go to the search box and type 1, then press the down arrow key fast 10 times in a row, when you finish pressing the down key, immediately do the same to the up key. There you'll see what's happening.

Comment: Isn't there a `skip()` effect? That's what I'm trying to achieve, need to skip the previous animation if the next animation is triggered.